# Using Javascript to check an item's properties

Tags: javascript, object, if-statement, boolean

I am creating a lame text-based game, and I want each box to be able to have either nothing, the player, a monster, or a heath pack on it.  I have an array of objects like so:

```
var squares = [

    square1 = { //each square with its own number
        player:false,
        monster:false,
        healthPack:false
    },

    square2 = {
        player:false,
        monster:false,
        healthPack:false
    }

];
```

and if any one of those is on the square i change it to true, i want to know how to check if any are already true.

this is what i want to know:

```
for ( var i in sqaures[x] ) {
     if( what do i put here??? == true ) return;
}
```

or if there is another pre-written way?

Comment: Any reason not to format your code?

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: [http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks][link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev sorry was lazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a helper function like this.

Javascript

```
function isSquareTrue(square) {
    var i;

    for (i in square) {
        if (square.hasOwnProperty(i) && square[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

var squareXX = { //each square with its own number
    player: false,
    monster: false,
    healthPack: false
}

console.log(isSquareTrue(squareXX));
```

On <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/WdAF5/)</kbd>

Update: For changed question demonstrating the squares in an array

Javascript

```
function anySquaresTrue(arrayOfSquares) {
    var length,
        index,
        property,
        square;

    for (index = 0, length = arrayOfSquares.length; index < length; index += 1) {
        square = arrayOfSquares[index];
        for (property in square) {
            if (square.hasOwnProperty(property) && square[property]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

var squares = [{ //each square with its own number
        player: false,
        monster: false,
        healthPack: false
    }, {
        player: false,
        monster: false,
        healthPack: false
    }];

console.log(anySquaresTrue(squares));
```

On <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/jvTXm/)</kbd>

Comment: how do i do that for a array?

Comment: i didnt downvote man, your answer was nice for my unclear first version (i did mention array of objects though).

Comment: No problem, but someone did and it would have been nice for them to say why? Anyway, I updated to give you an example with an array of objects.

Comment: thanks based on you answer i created this fiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/jvTXm/2/ -- which was what i really wanted. answer accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var squareXX = { //each square with its own number
    player:false,
    monster:false,
    healthPack:true
    }
    for (key in squareXX) {
      if (squareXX[key] == true){
      alert("true is a " + key);
      }
    }
```

Try this code.
Should alert true is a healthPack.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean just this?

```
if ((player) || (monster) || (healthPack)) {...
```